# Delayed job failing with no method error after upgrading the ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, delayed-job

Heroku upgraded my ruby version.

```
   Old: ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]
   New: ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-linux]
```

After that delayed job is not working in heroku. It is failing.

```
{undefined method `get' for #<Module:0x00000008f71b...
```

How to fix it.

I am using,

```
gem "delayed_job", "2.1.4"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this line to config/application.rb

```
YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'psych'
```

and installed `gem "psych"`

Solved the problem..

Answer (score 0):

You should update your gem by writing these commands on console....

```
1. rails generate delayed_job:upgrade
2. rake db:migrate.
```

hope this works... :)

Comment: Try this.. In gem file gem 'delayed_job', "3.0.1" and gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
then run bundle update >> then run >> 1. rails generate delayed_job:upgrade
2. rake db:migrate.

Comment: i am not using gem 'delayed_job_active_record'. Any other solution

Comment: then try to update your rvm so it will update patch level and do this.. may be this works >> 1. cd <app-name> 2. echo "rvm use 1.9.3-p385@<gemset-name" > .rvmrc 3. then go back to home directory and come back into ur original directory. now run bundle update with ur old gem file. this will make a new gemlock file so on heroku this will not be affected. hope this works.